# SSMS Query Shortcuts lost after Windows update

Tags: ssms, windows-update

I've set some custom query shortcuts to SQL Server Management Studio via Options->Environent->Keyboard->Query Shortcuts page. Everytime Windows gets an update, my custom shortcuts are lost and I have to set them again.

Any ideas how to prevent this and make my settings persistent?

I use SSMS v18.0 and Windows10 up to date.

Comment: Thank you guys. It seems like there is no cure for this problem at the moment. Windows updates also mess with my device drivers, maybe opting out of Insider program is best for me.

Answer (score 0):

When I wanted to do it, I could not find a way.

The best option is to go to TOOLS > Import and Export settings > Export Selected Settings > Options > Environment > Keyboard and check the box.

Then you can import back after a wipeout!

Comment: Thank you. Tried it and got errors. I think this may indicate my SSMS installation may have problems.

_"Your settings were exported, but there were some errors.

Error 1:  Failed to export settings for '#20116' [code 6714]
Error 2:  Failed to export settings for '#100' [code 6714] (...)"_

Comment: Yes seems that way.